# array returned from promise wont render in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to work this out for a VERY long time, but I just cannot. I do not understand why an array, whose contents I console.log, and clearly see it is not empty, and has the elements I want in it, is not being rendered on the page when I run my react native app. My code is below, please help guys

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function PaymentsScreen() {

  const [renderedData, setRenderedData] = React.useState(new Array<string>());

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  async function parseData() {
    const payments = await getData();

    if (payments) {

        const res = payments
        .filter((e: any[]) => e[1] && e.includes('{'))
        .map((e: any[]) => e[1]);
        
        setRenderedData(res);
    }

    return renderedData;
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    parseData()
  });
 
  return (

    <View>

      {renderedData.map(data => <Text>{data}</Text> )}

    </View>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont push directly the data on renderedData

you should use setRenderedData

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
        const res = result
           .filter((e: any[]) => e[1] && e.includes('{'))
           .map((e: any[]) => e[1]);
        setRenderedData(res);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
   }
   fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Also you should call `parseData` inside `useEffect` hook. Or you'll get an infinite fetch-update loop.

Comment: are you sure this works? I am getting an infinite loop

Comment: dont forget to refactor with useEffect. Editing to explain better

Comment: I updated my code, thanks for your suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: may be result need some logic to parse. saw that you are waiting for an array

Comment: Yes, I am waiting for the promise to resolve but it should not be this complicated

Comment: debug the `result`, and paste here, i will try help

Comment: I actually ran console.log(renderedData) in that block of code for useEffect, and it returned [], I have no idea why

Comment: `const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);` and `console.log(result)`

Comment: result is perfect, it is exactly what i want, so that is not the problem

Comment: hmm, maybe the problem is on filter:  `.filter((e: any[]) => e[1] && e[1].includes('{'))`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your render function, since the data you are trying to render is an array, you need to loop through them to render each as text node.

```
 return (
      <View>
          { renderedData.map((item, key)=>(
            <Text key={key}> { item } </Text>)
          )}
      </View>
        );
```

Comment: I updated my code, thanks for your suggestion but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is bad practive to change the state directly. State should be considered as immutabe (see [explantion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)).
so change

```
renderedData.push(eachPayment[1]);
```

to

```
setRenderedData([...renderedData, eachPayment[1]);
```

Now, to the problem you are having, try to change

```
<Text> {renderedData} </Text>
```

to

```
{renderedData.map(data => <Text>{data}</Text> )}
```

try also change useEffect like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(renderedData.length === 0) {
        parseData();
    }
},[]);
```

Comment: I updated my code, thanks for your suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: Edited my answer. added useEffect edition. worse trying

Comment: I actually ran console.log(renderedData) in that block of code for useEffect, and it returned [], I have no idea why

Comment: it should be []. did you try to console log res?

Comment: res is [] as well

Comment: inside "parseData"? if so, then you know where your problem is (hint: ...filter...map...)

Comment: glad it helped, my pleasure